# How do I use readline's rl.on('line') multiple times in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, global-variables, global, readline

I need to take input from the user such as the listening and connecting port, I've tried seperating the rl.on('line')'s and I've tried using them inside one another. If the is some way to save the data from the line to a global variabel that would work too, but I don't know how.

```
const readline = require('readline')

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
})

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    const listenPort = line
    rl.on('line', (line) => {
        const connectPort = line
    })
})
```